# React typescript union type narrowing

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import { Chip } from "@mui/material";

type CourseFilterChipsRangeType = {
  labels: { from: string; to: string };
  values: { from: number; to: number };
  toggler: (from: number, to: number) => void;
};

type CourseFilterChipsCheckType = {
  labels: string[];
  toggler: (value: string) => void;
  values?: never
};

type CourseFilterChipsProps = CourseFilterChipsRangeType | CourseFilterChipsCheckType;

const CourseFilterChips = (props: CourseFilterChipsProps) => {
  const { labels, toggler, values } = props;
  let chips: JSX.Element[];

  if (Array.isArray(labels)) {
    chips = labels.map((label) => (
      <Chip
        onDelete={() =>
          toggler(label.toLowerCase())
        }
        label={label}
      />
    ));
  } 

  return (
    <>
      { chips }
    </>
  );
};

export default CourseFilterChips;
```

Hi.

I'm new to the react and typescript world and I'm facing a problem when narrowing react component props type.
I'm trying to narrow the props type based on what props are passing to component and the type of them.

typescript can't correctly narrow `toggler` function type based on other props and showing weird type for parameters.

[toggler detected type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAe7u.jpg)

does typescript can narrow the whole props type based on narrowing one of the properties of it?

if yes, so why it can't narrow `toggler` function type correctly?
if no, then how do I narrow down the whole props type to one of it union types?

thanks.
and sorry if I have any typos in my writing, English ain't my native.

Comment: Why do you need `if (Array.isArray(labels))` check? Seems like it's redundant. You can return the whole `map`ed jsx in the `return` clause without storing it inside a `chips` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran a modified version of your code on `https://playcode.io/typescript` and it looks like it works as expected.

Here's the code I've used to test this:

```
type CourseFilterChipsRangeType = {
  labels: { from: string; to: string };
  values: { from: number; to: number };
  toggler: (from: number, to: number) => void;
};

type CourseFilterChipsCheckType = {
  labels: string[];
  toggler: (value: string) => void;
  values?: never
};

type MergedType = CourseFilterChipsCheckType | CourseFilterChipsRangeType;

const fn = (props: MergedType) => {
 console.log(props);
}

fn({ 
  labels: ['label1', 'label2'],
  toggler: (v: string) => console.log(v),
});

fn({
  labels: {
    from: 'a',
    to: 'z',
  },
  toggler: (from: number, to: number) => { console.log(from, to); },
  values: {
    from: 1,
    to: 9,
  },
});
```

Could you show me an example of how you use your component? The error might be there.

Comment: thanks for answering. the problem is not how I use the component. the problem is how I narrow down the type of the props correctly

Comment: Well, it looks correct to me and if you copy that code to the playground I mentioned you can see proper types so the error might be caused by something else.